# rattle at very low speed

Tags: clutch, rattle

when in very low speed I get rattling,this had started only in when in 1st or 2nd gear and pulling away but recently I hear it when not in gear, could this still be caused by release/throw out bearing? as I read on here that could be the cause when in low gear but there was no suggestion it can occur while free-rolling.

Comment: First thing, look for loose objects in the cabin, glove box and boot (trunk). I have a low speed rattle in a car, but it comes from one of the interior door catches.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be a throw-out bearing causing your rattle, it's much more likely something has come loose and over time has gotten worse. I'd be looking at heat shields, exhaust pipes, plastic covers and the like.